# How to show that $O(\sum_1^{\infty} n^{1-{2\sigma}} e^{-\delta n} \sum_1^{n/2} 1/r )=O({\delta}^{2 \sigma -2} \log \dfrac{1}{\delta})$?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, estimation

The following lemma is from Titchmarsh's The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function:

[image]

I have difficulties in getting both the estimates:

1- $O((\sum_1^{\infty} n^{-{\sigma}} e^{-\delta n})^2) = O((\int_1^{\infty} x^{-{\sigma}} e^{-\delta x})^2)$, so how to estimate the integral or any other way to get $O({\delta}^{2 \sigma -2})$?

2- $O(\sum_1^{\infty} n^{1-{2\sigma}} e^{-\delta n} \sum_1^{n/2} 1/r )= O(\sum_1^{\infty} n^{1-{2\sigma}} e^{-\delta n} \log n) = O(\int_1^{\infty} x^{1-{2\sigma}} e^{-\delta x} \log x )$, so how to estimate the integral or any other way to get $O({\delta}^{2 \sigma -2} \log \dfrac{1}{\delta})$?

WolframAlpha couldn't be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these estimates rely on the same basic idea, which is that after a basic substitution you get the bound multiplied by some integral that obviously converges to some value independent of $\delta$.

I'll look at the first one. The second is essentially the same.

As you've noticed, the first estimate reduces to studying the (square of the) integral

$$ \int_1^\infty t^{-\sigma} e^{-\delta t} dt = \int_1^\infty t^{1 - \sigma} e^{-\delta t} \frac{dt}{t}. $$
Perform the change of variables $t \mapsto \tfrac{t}{\delta}$ to see that this is
$$ \int_\delta^\infty (t/\delta)^{1 - \sigma} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} = \delta^{\sigma - 1} \int_\delta^\infty t^{1 - \sigma} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t}. $$
The behavior of the integral on the right depends on what $\sigma$ and $\delta$ are. If $\sigma < 1$, then the integral converges
$$ \int_\delta^\infty t^{1 - \sigma} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} \leq \int_0^\infty t^{1 - \sigma}{e^{-t}} \frac{dt}{t} = \Gamma(1 - \sigma) < \infty. $$
If $\delta \geq 1$, then also have
$$ \int_\delta^\infty t^{1 - \sigma} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} \leq \int_1^\infty t^{1 - \sigma}e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} = O_\sigma(1).$$
But if $\delta$ is allowed to be arbitrarily small and $\sigma \geq 1$, then more care is necessary.

I presume that the bound is for fixed $\sigma$ as $\delta \to \infty$, in which case the two simple cases above are sufficient. This isn't clear from the image.

If desired, it is possible to give more precise bounds. The integral
$$ \int_\delta^\infty t^{1 - \sigma} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} = \Gamma(1 - \sigma, \delta) $$
is the "upper incomplete gamma function". Very good bounds and approximations are known. I wouldn't expect these to be necessary for whatever application Titchmarsh has in mind.

The conclusion is that if either $\delta \geq 1$ or if $\sigma < 1$, then
$$ \int_1^\infty t^{-\sigma} e^{-\delta t} dt = \delta^{\sigma - 1} O_\sigma(1). $$

A similar change-of-variables and basic bounding applies for the second sum (and with the same regions of where these simple bounds work).